# Why are there key_type and value_type in std::set

Tags: c++, set

After reading this link: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set, I just found that there were two defined types: `key_type` and `value_type` in the class `std::set`. It seems that they are exactly the same thing.

Well, this may be a stupid question but I still want to ask why. Isn't one enough? Why are there two types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the stl containers have `value_type`, and all the associative containers (including `std::set`, `std::map`, `std::multiset`, `std::multimap`) and unordered associative containers (including `std::unordered_set`, `std::unordered_map`, `std::unordered_multiset`, `std::unordered_multimap`) have `key_type`, that means you can perform some general processing (with templates especially) on these containers with the member types.

Comment: ahh, ok, I got it.